# How to properly tighten a wheel on a bench grinder?

Tags: tools

I just bought a 8" bench grinder from Harbor Freight to clean up some automotive parts with a wire wheel. On the left side of the grinder has a left hand threaded nut on it, while the other side has a right hand threaded nut. If I use two wrenches and try to tighten one side the other side will loosen. No matter how much I try this loosing/tightening thing keeps going back and forth. There is no special tool included and there doesn't seem to be a good place to hold the shaft in-place. Is there some special trick to get these wheels attached and secured?

Comment: Whomever voted to close, remember that we have had questions about tools asked on here before, most recently about breaking a ratchet due to hammering on it ...

Comment: The hand-held grinders I have used have generally had a button that pushes a mechanical pawl in to lock the shaft - I presume this doesn't?

Comment: It doesn't have a locking button or mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if OSHA would approve but the method I use is to wedge a screwdriver between the toolrest and the wheel. Then tighten the nut. It doesn't need to be jammed in real tight just enough to snug up the nut.